# Calling method from another class, return is Enumeration yielded no results

Tags: c#, ienumerable

**cGetComponents.cs**

```
 public class cGetComponents
 {    
    public IEnumerable<Component> EnumerateComponents(object formobj)
    {
      return from field in GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
             where typeof(Component).IsAssignableFrom(field.FieldType)
             let component = (Component)field.GetValue(formobj)
             where component != null
             select component;
     }
 }
```

**Form1.cs**

```
cGetComponentsobj = new cGetComponents();  
IEnumerable<Component> c = obj.EnumerateComponents(this);
```

Why c is empty, without results? If I put function EnumerateComponents() inside Form1 then c has some elements.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `from field in formobj.GetType().GetFields()...`?

Comment: `EnumerateComponents<T>(T instance) .. instance.GetType()`

Comment: @JohanP you are right. This was missing. Thanks!